# Set Tax Rate in Magento based on Discount / Coupon Code

Tags: magento

I've been trying to set a tax rate or customer class rate for magento based on the discount code used. Im only using the discount code as I can use it for a input.

Does anyone have any idea how this can achieved or any pointers?

Kind Regards

Chris

Comment: Shouldn't the tax rate be set by the country and the product, not the customer?

Comment: Its a case of the customer in this instance has to specifiy that they are tax exempt for these certain products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing for this. Should prove quite useful. Copy this file app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php to app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php then on line 178 theres this function

```
 public function getRate($request)
    {
        if (!$request->getCountryId() || !$request->getCustomerClassId() || !$request->getProductClassId()) {
            return 0;
        }

    $cacheKey = $this->_getRequestCacheKey($request);
    if (!isset($this->_rateCache[$cacheKey])) {
        $this->unsRateValue();
        $this->unsCalculationProcess();
        $this->unsEventModuleId();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('tax_rate_data_fetch', array('request'=>$request));
        if (!$this->hasRateValue()) {
            $rateInfo = $this->_getResource()->getRateInfo($request);
            $this->setCalculationProcess($rateInfo['process']);
            $this->setRateValue($rateInfo['value']);
        } else {
            $this->setCalculationProcess($this->_formCalculationProcess());
        }
        $this->_rateCache[$cacheKey] = $this->getRateValue();
        $this->_rateCalculationProcess[$cacheKey] = $this->getCalculationProcess();
    }
    return $this->_rateCache[$cacheKey];
}
```

I've changed this to this. Its a hardcoded Discount Code and Product Tax Class Id based on my requirements for this project.

```
public function getRate($request)
    {
        if (!$request->getCountryId() || !$request->getCustomerClassId() || !$request->getProductClassId()) {
            return 0;
        }

    $cacheKey = $this->_getRequestCacheKey($request);
    if (!isset($this->_rateCache[$cacheKey])) {
        $this->unsRateValue();
        $this->unsCalculationProcess();
        $this->unsEventModuleId();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('tax_rate_data_fetch', array('request'=>$request));
        if (!$this->hasRateValue()) {
            $rateInfo = $this->_getResource()->getRateInfo($request);
            $this->setCalculationProcess($rateInfo['process']);
            $thisDiscountCode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
            $thisProductClassCode = $request->getProductClassId();
            if($thisDiscountCode == "0000" && $thisProductClassCode == "5"):
            $this->setRateValue(0);
            else:    
            $this->setRateValue($rateInfo['value']);
            endif;            
        } else {
            $this->setCalculationProcess($this->_formCalculationProcess());
        }
        $this->_rateCache[$cacheKey] = $this->getRateValue();
        $this->_rateCalculationProcess[$cacheKey] = $this->getCalculationProcess();
    }
    return $this->_rateCache[$cacheKey];
}
```

Cheers for the help on this

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer... helped me to solve a unrelated, yet similar problem of changing the shipping price with coupon code!

Answer (score 2):

There is no default way of doing this. You should set the customer's class for them through admin, that way they get their specific tax rate always without having to input anything.

Comment: Cheers for the answer clockwork, I've figured out a way of doing this via the calculation.php. It is essentially modifying core code but I'm gonna combine it with the product tax class to get what I want. Will try to remember to post the code here once done. Thanks